# Linux how to add suffix to a filename with its parent directory

Tags: linux, shell, rename

I have these files and many others :

```
$ ls *
blue-3454534:
banana.txt  file1.txt

green-junkjunk:
fever.txt   vegan.txt

yellow-junkkkjunkkk:
funny.txt   sunny.txt
```

I would like to run a command (loop) that would rename :

- banana.txt to blue_banana.txt
- file1.txt to blue_file1.txt
- fever.txt to green_fever.txt
- vegan.txt to green_vegan.txt
- funny.txt to yellow_funny.txt
- sunny.txt to yellow_sunny.txt

So as you understand it would put at the beginning (prefix) its parent directory name, until the dash (and ignore the remaining after the dash)

Ideally I would use mv or rename command, in a 1 command line loop.

Also, the renamed files should stay in the directory they are already.

Thank you for your help.

PS : there is no space nowhere nor in filename nor in directory name

Comment: Should the renamed files remain in their subdirectories, so you'd have `blue/blue_banana.txt` etc.?

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes they should remain. Thanks

Comment: Then please update the question to reflect that. And see @Barmar's comment.

Comment: @Barmar I only managed to do `for subdir in *; do mv $subdir/file.txt $subdir.txt; done` , but it renames the whole filename to parent directory name.

Comment: Do a nested loop for the files. `for file in $subdir/*; do ... `

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the name of the directory is stored in the variable `subdir`, and the name of the file (without directory part) is stored in the variable file, one way to rename it in the desired way is

```
cd $subdir
mv $file ${subdir%-*}_$file
cd -
```

The `%-*` part gets you the part of the directoryname before the dash.

This solution works for bash, zsh, and ksh.

For details, how the `%-` expansion works, see the excellent explanation in the *bash* manpage under the heading *Parameter Expansion*. For Zsh, it is in the man page called *zshexpn* and found under the heading *PARAMETER EXPANSION* (all uppercase). For *ksh*, the name of the section is simply *Parameters*.

Comment: You may want to add that you are relying on *parameter expansion with substring removal* and explain what that is and how it is used (in more than this one isolated case). You need not go into *parameter expansion with substring replacement*, but you should cover at least the cases of `'%'`, `'%%'`, `'#'` and `'##'`.

Comment: Good point. These things are a bit difficult to locate in the man pages, I will point out where to find it (the explanations in the man pages are better than any I can write myself)...